# User management and key share with React +JWT+Express

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have created signup and login page using React+express+JWT+MySQL which is running in one server (8080). This server acts like SSO and is mainly used for authentication.

I have a couple of apps(3000,3001,3002) which perform the authorization part (reads JWT from a cookie). Now the question is,

1. what would be the best way to share the user data to these servers from authentication server?
2. I also have to share the JWT secret key whenever it is changed in the authentication server.
3. What's the ideal way to implement refresh key?
4. How often should I change secret key and is there a way I can automate this process?